# VBA run time error 1004 when I protect the sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a shared workbook with two sheets, one sheet has many formulas, so I want to protect the "sheet 1".

I also cut and pasted some VBA code into the "sheet 1".  The VBA works great until I protect the sheet. But when I protect the sheet a run time error 4 shows.

Any ideas what is wrong?

**Project**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
StartBlink 
End Sub 

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 
StopBlink 
End Sub
```

**Module1**

```
Public RunWhen As Double Sub StartBlink() 
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Font 
    If .ColorIndex = 3 Then   
        .ColorIndex = 2 
    Else 
        .ColorIndex = 3 
    End If 
End With 

RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , True 
End Sub 

Sub StopBlink() 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Font.ColorIndex = _ 
    xlColorIndexAutomatic Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , False 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you're trying to achieve? A snippet of the VBA code might help too. Would the VBA change anything in the sheet? I'd assume if it's protected that a VBA script can't change it anymore. Just a guess though.

Comment: Better you share the code with us will help us to find & fix the error !

Comment: *when I protect the sheet* What parameters of Worksheet.Protect method do you set? *Any ideas* Remove protecion, perform action, restore protection. VBA can do it easily...

Comment: UNDER VBA PROJECT-THISWORKBOOK- CODE AS FOLLOWS                                      Private Sub Workbook_Open()
StartBlink
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
StopBlink
End Sub

Comment: UNDER MODULE1                                        Public RunWhen As Double

Sub StartBlink()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Font
If .ColorIndex = 3 Then
.ColorIndex = 2
Else
.ColorIndex = 3
End If
End With
RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , True
End Sub

Sub StopBlink()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Font.ColorIndex = _
xlColorIndexAutomatic
Application.OnTime RunWhen, "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!StartBlink", , False
End Sub

Comment: All additional info MUST be added to a question text. Use [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1356100/edit) link under the question.

Comment: In your VBA macro, start with unprotecting the sheet first, then at the end, protect the sheet. Do note, this means you will be storing the password of the sheet in the macro so it can be retrieved, but only by those who are experienced users. It's the only way.

Comment: As per your advice In my VBA macro, start with unprotecting the sheet first, then at the end, protect the sheet.  But when I protect the sheet throug "review" menu sheet not protect.  pl. help

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to protect A1 cell? I think if you unprotect (remove locked checkmark from format cells -> protection -> locked) only A1 Cell and protect all the rest of the sheet, code will run and blink